# Make a UI Text pop for a few seconds on Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to coding, been learning for the past year and I'm currently working on an assignment for school and i can't figure out this bit of code for the love of my life.

I have an item that when the player interacts with it, executes this:

```
void Update ()
{
     if (isPlayerNear && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && Avatar.strenghtAttribute >= 2f)
    {
        levelUp.LevelUp();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

My level up function is basically this:

```
public void LevelUp()
{
     playerLevelText.text = ("You have gained a level!");
     strenghtAttribute++;
     intellectAttribute++;
     playerLevel++;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make playerLevelText.Text appear on the screen but only appear for a few seconds and I can't figure out how to make that work. Would anyone be kind enough to give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set the text to be blank, or enable/disable the text object. I'd recommend using a coroutine for this.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (isPlayerNear && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && Avatar.strenghtAttribute >= 2f)
    {
        levelUp.InitializeLevelUp());
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Since you are destroying the gameobject calling the coroutine, the coroutine will stop. A workaround is to call a normal function in your other script, which then calls the coroutine, so execution stays within the one script (there might be a cleaner way to do this).

```
public void InitializeLevelUp()
{
    StartCoroutine(LevelUp());
}
public IEnumerator LevelUp()
{
     playerLevelText.text = ("You have gained a level!");
     strenghtAttribute++;
     intellectAttribute++;
     playerLevel++;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
     playerLevelText.text = "";
     //alternatively, set the text object inactive   
}
```

Comment: I think i forgot to mention that both of this functions exist on different game objects, does that matter?

Comment: yes, since you are destroying the gameobject that is calling the coroutine, it will not be able to finish. you can either delay the destruction `Destroy(gameObject, 2.1f)`. Or trigger a normal function in your other script, which starts the coroutine - I've made this edit above

Comment: You are the best, this works perfectly, thank you so much!